# numeric value out of range Sum=> value out of range CDS view

Tags: abap

I have created CDS view. some detail as below.

```
@AbapCatalog.sqlViewName: 'ZUA_HOURS'
@AbapCatalog.compiler.compareFilter: true
@AccessControl.authorizationCheck: #CHECK
@ClientDependent: true
@EndUserText.label: 'Employee hours reported'
define view Z_Hours
as select from catsdb 
 {
  key pernr,
  sum(catshours) as totalHours
} 
group by pernr
```

Detail of error message in ST22 is below.

Database error text: "SQL message: numeric value out of range: not enough space for packed decimal at function **copy_trex_field_Fixed8_check**() (at pos 54) "

experts please advise for the above error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The F1 help for `SUM` says that summing retains the column's original data type.

It also says that:

> The types DF16_..., DF34_... for decimal free floating numbers are not supported.

I assume that `catshours` is such a decimal type? If so, try to cast it to another data type before summing.